# Any way to add a Marker or a Pin on PDF files in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, pdf, marker

I want to place marker or a customizable marker that opens up the current status screen of the marker on PDF files in a Flutter application. I have tried 4-5 PDF viewers and editors on pub, tried using stacks, tried to convert PDF into PNG using native_pdf_renderer. But I simply cannot get it to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
I have attached an image below for a preview of what I want to do.
(Cannot add image because of low rep)

[Customizable marker that opens up the current status screen of the marker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WjjVS.png)

Answer (score 0):

I have tried all libraries as well as created a separate library, in my opinion, you can follow these two ways:

- Self-writing library in native.
- Use inappbrowser to display pdf and add a customizable marker. (UI is very similar to native)

I recommend way 2.

Comment: Option 1 is out of the equation as I cannot write native iOS code (only Android) and I want native rather than webview, so no to option 2.